# Kan condition for bar construction

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, monads

Let $T$ be a monad on a [concrete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category) $\mathcal{C}$, and $A$ an algebra over $T$. The [bar construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bar+construction) is a simplicial object in the category $\mathcal{C}^T$ of algebras which we can think of a sort of "resolution" of $A$. Some of the arrows look like the following diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\cdots TTA \rightrightarrows TA \to A
\end{array}
$$
(I unfortunately cannot draw more arrows here. See the link above for a better picture.)

Now, is such a simplicial object a [Kan complex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+complex), or at least a [quasicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quasi-category)? Is there a filling condition for horns, in general? If not, what would be a counterexample?

Any reference would also be welcome.

Comment: Are you assuming that the objects of your category have underlying sets?

Comment: @FernandoMuro I could. What would that imply?

Comment: I don't know, maybe the answer depends on the properties of the 'underlying set' functor. It's definitely yes if this functor factors through the category of groups. Actually, I cannot make sense of your question unless you take underlying sets, since I don't know what the Kan condition is for simplicial sets in an arbitrary category.

Comment: @FernandoMuro I see. You are right, the nLab page talks briefly about a possible internalization, but it is unclear how it would be in the general case. So let's assume we are in a concrete category.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Why is it yes if there is an "underlying group"? That sounds interesting.

Comment: @geodude A simplicial group is always a Kan complex.

Comment: If C=Sets and T is the monoid for pointed sets, and $A=(A,a_0)$, then the Bar construction, as a simplicial set, is the union of $A \times \Delta[0]$ (i.e. const. simp. set on A) with $\Delta[1]$ along $\Delta[0]$ identified as $a_0 \in A$. It is not Kan, but it is a quasicategory.

Comment: [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00872942) gives a definition of the Kan condition for simplicial objects in any regular category, and proves that every simplicial object is Kan if and only if the category is Mal'cev, i.e. if and only every reflexive relation is an equivalence relation. This generalises Fernando Muro's observation about the functor factorising through the category of groups.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one sufficient (not necessary) condition to get a quasi-category: if $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks and $T$ is [cartesian](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monad). In particular, this implies that given any algebra $a:TA\to A$ in $\mathcal{C}$,
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
TTTA & \rightarrow & TTA\\
\downarrow^\mu & & \downarrow^\mu \\
TTA & \rightarrow & TA
\end{array}
$$

is a pullback diagram, which by its universal property gives a *unique* composition (not even up to homotopy). Therefore the bar construction for cartesian $T$ is the nerve of a category.

More interesting discussions can be found in the [comments of this post on the n-category café](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/05/on_the_bar_construction.html#c009956).

More answers are welcome!